# System.Diagnostics.StackFrame.GetFrame(index) not found in mscorlib

Tags: c#, .net

I created two console applications, both targeting v4.5.2 of the .NET framework.

```
class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        var callerName = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1)?.GetMethod()?.Name;

        Console.WriteLine($"Dispose called by {callerName}.");
    }
}
```

which run perfectly well.

In the other, I have the following, which are in effect the same.

```
return Disposable.Create(() =>
{
    var stackFrame = new StackFrame();
    var callingMethodBase = stackFrame.GetFrame(1)?.GetMethod();

    ...
});
```

But Visual Studio intellisense reports:

> 'StackFrame' does not contain a definition for 
>   'GetFrame' and no extension method 'GetFrame' 
>   accepting a first argument of type 'StackFrame' 
>   could be found (are you missing a using 
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

When I **Go to Definition** on the `StackFrames`class, I see the method `GetFrames` is absent from the class declaration of the `StackFrame` class. Both the assembly versions for **mscorlib** are the same, i.e. v4.0.0.0.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you are using `StackTrace`, but in the second you are using `StackFrame`.

Stack**Trace** has the method GetFrame(), but Stack**Frame** doesn't.

Comment: My bad. So ashamed. I should have looked harder.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - No worries, it happens to the best of us.